# Creating Peirce quincuncial map in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, reprojection-mathematics

I would like to create a Peirce quincuncial projection of vector data using QGIS.

A similar question was asked here several years ago, without apparent satisfactory answer. Someone offered a [link to Github code in a comment](https://github.com/cspersonal/peirce-quincuncial-projection/blob/master/peirceQuincuncialProjection.R), but I don't have the coding knowledge to know how to implement it or whether/how it can be used with QGIS.

How can I use that link, or do this another way?

Answer (score 1):

Look at this post : [how to produce a Peirce quincuncial map?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31372/how-to-produce-a-peirce-quincuncial-map)

A OSGeo Proj.4 was made after : [Proj.4 with Peirce quincuncial projection](https://github.com/imagico/proj.4/tree/pq)

Maybe compile a new Proj.4 from specific files of this repository for using with QGIS ?
Here the [commit files for Peirce quincuncial projection](https://github.com/imagico/proj.4/commit/2bb8948f01aefb139c937cbf5c7838d82f381df6) in this repository.

And a python code for translating coordinates : [peircequincuncial.py](https://github.com/jonathf/cartopy/blob/8172cac7fc45cafc86573d408ce85b74258a9c28/lib/cartopy/peircequincuncial.py)